# What are default constants for NSLayoutConstraint?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nslayoutconstraint

In Xcode I can put some controls on the window's contentView and they get default spacing according to some unknown rules. This depends on control types that are constrained. For example, two `NSButton`s of *regular type* are separated by 12 points, but regular button and gradient button only by 8.

Also, vertical space depends too. Regular spacing is 8, but for two `NSTextField`s the spacing is 10, and for button below them even 20.

What are the rules and/or constants?

Comment: @Bimawa I got the answer below (if you are interested)

Comment: :) thx a lot I use Masonry library and it very helpful instrument for autolayouts ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't find it in the docs right now but it was mentioned in the various WWDC videos covering this topic -

*default* should refer to the various suggested defaults in the *Human Interface Guidelines*, i.e. using *default* will apply Apple's suggested settings.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I already found that `constraintsWithVisualFormat:…` also uses the defaults (and not just 8 or 20). Maybe I should stick to this method and not try to enforce them.

Comment: I recently found out that even installed constraints change their constant depending on types of controls! So, I decided to stick with the visual constructing method to obtain the defaults and then autolayout engine does all tricks *at runtime*. Probably these guys did not export the defaults, but do detect default spacings from the constraints and fix them on the fly. That's enough to solve my problem. Thanks!